# Python splitting string and get last part

Tags: python

I would like to split this string using python

```
string: ["Chiuso\n\n\n\n\r\nPARTE ISCHIA PORTO"]
```

after the \n\n\n\n\r\n char to get

```
output string: ["Parte ischia porto"]
```

I've tried

```
[![other_info][1]][1] = re.split("\n\n\n\n\r\n", string.capitalize())[1]
```

but I get an index out of range error.

Comment: `re.split("\n\n\n\n\r\n", "Chiuso\n\n\n\n\r\nPARTE ISCHIA PORTO".strip().capitalize())` works fine for me, I get `['Chiuso', 'parte ischia porto']`. Please give a [mcve] that recreates the issue. Also note you can use `r'\s{2,}'` to match any sequence of more than one whitespace character.

Comment: Nitpick: `["Chiuso\n\n\n\n\r\nPARTE ISCHIA PORTO"]` is not a string, it is a list. I suspect this is not a problem in your actual code, and just a quirk in the formatting of your post, but it's hard to say for sure without an MCVE.

Comment: @Daniela and `['Chiuso', 'parte ischia porto'][1]` gives you that, no `IndexError`. From what you've posted, I can't recreate the issue; if the input is really a list, I'd expect `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize'`.

Comment: Why you need `re` when you can do `str.split()` ?

Comment: Try `s.rsplit("\n")[-1].capitalize()`

Comment: @ScottBoston It worked - thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rsplit:

```
s = "Chiuso\n\n\n\n\r\nPARTE ISCHIA PORTO"

s.rsplit("\n")[-1].capitalize()
```

Output:

```
'Parte ischia porto'
```

Comment: If the input was "Chiuso\n\n\n\n\r\n                             PARTE ISCHIA PORTO" with 32 space characters before PARTE ISCHIA PORTO. How could I remove them? I'm just learning python and wouldn't go far without the help of the community

Comment: Try `import re` then use `re.split('\s\s+', s)[-1].capitalize()`